# ZTE Avid Plus screen isnt working

Tags: touchscreen

I woke up one morning and my phone worked perfectly fine. I went to the bathroom did the daily morning routine and when i checked my phone the screen went wack. I could'nt type my password and i couldnt swipe the screen to even type it. it typed in the numbers for the password but i wasnt doing it. it did it on its own, Seems like the screen calibration is off or something, i already restarted, turned it off, back on, and ftm moded it (on accident) and it still wont work. Do i need to factory reset?

Comment: did you have wet hands when you did it, by any chance? maybe all that's needed is a good wipe